# PYTHON: How to start each test with different capabilities?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, appium

I am writing tests for a mobile app, where the first screen is a Login screen. I do have that covered but in other tests I want to skip test_Login and go straight to test_DoStuffOnHomeScreen

What would be the best approach? I am using

```
def get_desired_caps(application):
    return dict(platformName='Android', deviceName="$DEVICE",
                application=PATH('../apps/' + app), appPackage='xxx',
                appActivity='xxx.MainActivity', newCommandTimeout=240, noReset='true', fullReset='false')
```

as my desired capabilities - when I run this without noReset and fullReset it's taking me to login screen, which is fine. But what about other scenarios? My starting session script looks like that

```
class StartSession(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = desired_capabilities.get_desired_capabilities('xxx.apk')
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    self.application = Application(self.driver)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

Which is then used in tests:

```
class LoginPage(StartSession):

    def test_login_with_valid_credentials(self):
```

Comment: make a method that will accept the parameter "noReset" so that you can pass the parameter depending on your requirement. I have done so in Java. If you want to see java code i can post it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample

```
public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public void setupDriver(boolean noReset) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "android device");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, noReset);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 600);
        caps.setCapability("udid", "your device udid");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "your appPackage name");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "your appActivity name");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + "your port number here" + "/wd/hub"), caps);
    }
```

Now when you want to reset your app to check from login screen you can call

```
setupDriver(false);
```

If you don't want to reset your app, just run

```
setupDriver(true);
```

Hope it helps you